# PHP PDO, Object, bindParam

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I don't manage to fill a table with a PHP Object with PDO and an object created from a JSON file. Do you see where the error comes from?
I use PHP5 & PostgreSQL

The code I wrote sucessfully adds the lines, but only the first column (field) of each row is filled, the others remain white.

My table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ' . $infoTableName . ' (field text,type text,expefactor boolean,iduser boolean,idcontext boolean,idaction boolean,params boolean,comment text)
```

My object looks like this:

```
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'timestamp' => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'idagent' => boolean false
      public 'idcontext' => boolean false
      public 'idaction' => boolean false
      public 'comment' => string 'ffff' (length=4)
  public 'order' => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'idagent' => boolean false
      public 'idcontext' => boolean false
      public 'idaction' => boolean false
      public 'comment' => string 'none' (length=4)
  public 'test' => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'idagent' => boolean false
      public 'idcontext' => boolean true
      public 'idaction' => boolean false
      public 'comment' => string 'y' (length=1)
```

And finally the PHP code:

```
$structure = json_decode($_POST['structure']);
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $infoTableName . " (field, iduser, idcontext, idaction, comment) VALUES (:field, :idagent, :idcontext, :idaction, :comment)"; //Prequery
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':field', $key);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idagent', $value->idagent);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idcontext', $value->idcontext);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idaction', $value->idaction);
            $stmt->bindParam(':comment', $value->comment);


            foreach ($structure as $key => &$value) {
                try {
                    var_dump($stmt->execute());
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    var_dump($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
```

Do you see the error?
Thanks a lot.

EDIT: It looks like I am asking a too much with object in binding functions, still, here is a little workaround:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':field', $key);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idagent', $idagent);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idcontext', $idcontext);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idaction', $idaction);
            $stmt->bindParam(':comment', $comment);


            foreach ($structure as $key => &$value) {
                $idagent = $value->idagent;
                $idcontext = $value->idcontext;
                $idaction = $value->idaction;
                $comment = $value->comment;
                try {
                    var_dump($stmt->execute());
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    var_dump($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
```

The reason bindParam() doesn't work is when I iterate thru the $structure, $value is reinstanciated, resulting in the references being changed... I first thought &$value would help, but it looks like not.

Comment: You're trying to use `$value->...` before `$value` is ever defined...!?

Comment: Like they do here: [link](http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and it's the official php manual. Maybe this doesn't work the same with objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I am asking a too much with object in binding functions, still, here is a little workaround:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':field', $key);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idagent', $idagent);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idcontext', $idcontext);
            $stmt->bindParam(':idaction', $idaction);
            $stmt->bindParam(':comment', $comment);


            foreach ($structure as $key => &$value) {
                $idagent = $value->idagent;
                $idcontext = $value->idcontext;
                $idaction = $value->idaction;
                $comment = $value->comment;
                try {
                    var_dump($stmt->execute());
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    var_dump($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
```

The reason bindParam() doesn't work is when I iterate thru the $structure, $value is reinstanciated, resulting in the references being changed... I first thought &$value would help, but it looks like not.

Answer (score 1):

> *Like they do here: ...*

No, they do not. Look again:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$name = 'one';
$stmt->execute();
```

They are binding the variable `$name` by reference and then assign a value to `$name`.
You on the other hand are doing:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':idagent', $value->idagent);
foreach ($structure as $key => &$value) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

You are binding `$value->idagent` by reference (I'm not actually sure if that works, creating an implicit object...?!), and then you're reference-overwriting `$value`. If at all, you should be assigning a value to `$value->idagent`, which was bound. Just replacing the `$value` object is not the same thing at all. PHP isn't so intelligent that it tracks that you bound the `idagent` attribute of that object and will reconstruct that after you have switched the underlying object. That's a little too meta.

I think in this case it's most useful to use `bindValue` inside your `foreach` loop and bind the existing values there.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
foreach ($structure as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':field', $key);
    $stmt->bindValue(':idagent', $value->idagent);
    $stmt->bindValue(':idcontext', $value->idcontext);
    $stmt->bindValue(':idaction', $value->idaction);
    $stmt->bindValue(':comment', $value->comment);
    $stmt->execute()
}
```

Comment: Yep, I asked too much with binding objects values... But it doesn't work your way too, I tried it before and got this error everytime: "SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation". Still, I made a little workaround.

Comment: And I'm not sure there's a point in redifining bindValue/bindParam everytime you iterate (the way it's documented).

Comment: IMO it's the most straight forward approach. It hardly makes any difference except in syntax.

Comment: Yep, moreover, binding before instanciating looks a bit strange at first sight.